# Kendo UI 2013 Grid implement parent-child (expand-collapse)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm new with kendo ui and mvc.

Does any one know how to implement a parent-child result in Kendo grid with expand/collapse behavior?

Comment: Kendo TreeList widget might be more along the lines of what you're after: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/index

Comment: @Dinglemeyer
Treelist is available in the latest kendo version :(

Current version used by client is 2013

Answer (score 2):

You can find an example [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/hierarchy).

Basically your main grid will need to point to a grid template, using `ClientDetailTemplateId()`. Then you create a template which will be your child grids.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.EmployeeViewModel>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(e => e.FirstName).Width(110);
            columns.Bound(e => e.LastName).Width(110);
            columns.Bound(e => e.Country).Width(110);
            columns.Bound(e => e.City).Width(110);
            columns.Bound(e => e.Title);

        })               
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable()
        .Scrollable()
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:600px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(6)
            .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Employees", "Grid"))            
        )        
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
)

<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.OrderViewModel>()
            .Name("grid_#=EmployeeID#") // template expression, to be evaluated in the master context
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Width(110);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ShipCountry).Width(110);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress).ClientTemplate("\\#= ShipAddress \\#"); // escaped template expression, to be evaluated in the child/detail context
                columns.Bound(o => o.ShipName).Width(300);
            })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(10)
                .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Orders", "Grid", new { employeeID = "#=EmployeeID#" }))
            )
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .ToClientTemplate()
    )
</script>
<script>
    function dataBound() {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort sir.
I'll try this one and hope it also support multiple parent-child (treeview like behavior)

Comment: Hi Sir Nicholas.

How can i implement the expand all underlying elements including child record with another child info?

Im trying to simulate from a simple grid process

Comment: If you're trying to expand parent/child multiple levels down you might be better off using a TreeList kendo widget instead of grid? telerik link: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/index

Comment: @ChrisSarsonas maybe the child grid can have its own child grid template set? Haven't tried that myself though.

Comment: @Nicholas actually im also thinking that suggestion of yours in which the  child should have a template also calling the template itself. but ill try that,and if not.. look for a possible solution.

Comment: @Dinglemeyer hope the said method/property is available in kendo 2013.

Hope it works.

Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @Nicholas i tried already putting a detail template inside the detail template and the result was the grid freezes as well as the browser (run by dojo) :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample simple grid (parent-child not yet working)
    
        $(function () {

```
        var employee = [
            { empID: 1, lastName: "Sarsonas", firstName: "Christine", ReportingTo: 0, Subordinate: {} },
            { empID: 2, lastName: "Sarsonas", firstName: "Alyssa", ReportingTo: 0, Subordinate: {} },
            { empID: 3, lastName: "Sarsonas", firstName: "Avril", ReportingTo: 0, Subordinate: {} },
            {
                empID: 10, lastName: "Uchiha", firstName: "Sasuke", ReportingTo: 1,
                Subordinate: { empID: 100, lastName: "Uzumaki", firstName: "Naruto", ReportingTo: 10 }
            }
        ];


        $("#TestGrid").kendoGrid({
            columns: [
                { title: "EmpID", field: "empID" },
                { title: "LastName", field: "lastName"},
                { title: "FirstName", field: "firstName" },
                { title: "ReportingTo", field: "ReportingTo" }
            ],
            dataSource: {
                data: employee
            }
    });
});
</script>
```